# Polymer Framework : how to determine the active page with attribute "changed" event handler

Tags: polymer

Trying to do some simple animations for a shopping cart, but seem to be snagged on a couple of high level issues.

I wanted to be able to execute the animations when my cart is empty, so I put some coding in the attribute "changed" for my cart attribute.

But it seems the changed event handler is being called even when the page is not active, I only want to execute when this core-animated-page is active

Here is my code, which the part where I use "***document.querySelector('html /deep/ #cart[active]')***" is not working, and seems hacky.  How can I do this better?

```
isloaded: false,
    created : function(){
       this.isloaded = true;
    },
    cartChanged: function() {
        //hide cart if no items  
        if(document.querySelector('html /deep/ #cart[active]')){
            console.log("cart.length:" + this.cart.length + " isloaded: " + this.isloaded)

            if (this.cart.length == 0) {
                if (this.isloaded) {
                    this.$.carthasitems.setAttribute('hidden', '');                   
                } else {
                    this.$.cartemptycontainer.classList.add('transparent');

                    this.$.cartanimations.toggleSlide(
                        this.$.carttotalscontainer, 
                        .5,
                        this.$.cartanimations.fadeInUp(this.$.cartemptycontainer, .5)
                        );
                }               
            }
            this.isloaded = false;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advanced,
David

Comment: Can you post more code. Where does the `#cart[active]` node live? Where are you using `core-animated-pages`?

Comment: Hi, I managed to create a creative solution to the problem:

Comment: Hi, I managed to create a creative solution to the problem:

In the parent page where your core-animated-pages is I created an attribute called active page, which is set to the selectedPage:

<core-animated-pages id="pages" selected="{{selectedPage}}" transitions="slide-up" >
 <cart-page id="cart" name="cart"  cart="{{cart}}"  activepage="{{ selectedPage }}"></page-cart>
</core-animated-pages>

>> see part two below

Comment: In page-cart
In your javascript listen to the attribute "changed" event handler for active page and check to see if activepage is the current page "cart":

 <polymer-element name="page-cart" attribute="cart-page">

 <script>
 Polymer({
 cartChanged: function(){
 if (this.activepage == "cart") {
 // do mock page load actions here
 }
 })

 </script>

</polymer-element>

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using Polymer 0.5 based on mentioning core-animated-page. So first thing is just that you'll probably get better support & mileage by moving to Polymer 1.0 which is the supported library going forward.

And if you do move to Polymer 1.0 & base your app on https://github.com/polymerelements/polymer-starter-kit then it includes a basic router that you could leverage to know which page (i.e. route) is active.

Comment: Yeah, I am finding this all over my app now, if you include a component more than once in a SPA, the encapsulated JS can get called on ready or domready even when the core-animated-page is not active.  Does anyone know how to work around this "feature"?